# How to make paths in package.json system independent?

Tags: json, node.js

I am learning nodejs on edx and stumbled over the following issue. You can run an express application (or other applications) via `npm start` if the command is added in the `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "express-hello-world",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": ".\\node_modules\\.bin\\node-dev server.js"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "node-dev": "3.1.3"
  }
}
```

Here, I used the windows style of the path with backslashes. However, what if I want to deploy the package on different platforms? Do I have to specify multiple paths? Cause I cannot run something like `path.join` in the json file right?

What is the best way to specify this path in a way that it (at least) runs on W10, Linux, MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

The binaries in the scripts will be resolved by the npm internally, so you can have:

```
"scripts": {
    "start": "node-dev server.js"
},
```

and it should work even if it's not globally installed

It's mentioned in the [documentation here](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts#path)

Comment: What if the path is not standard? It could be part of a bigger package.

Comment: What do you mean not standard? The `package.json` has a [bin](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#bin) field describing what binaries are provided

Comment: Well, in the tutorial the teacher said: "On most computers this path is not configured". That is the reason why he changed `node-dev server.js` to the version containing the relative path. But the path depends on the system now. If I download the package and use it on Linux it would not work anymore.